# Javascript remove string from array

Tags: javascript

I have array:

```
var data = [];
data.genre = [ 'AAAA', '2', 'CCCc', '3', 'dDdDD' ];
```

a need to remove all string from array and return only numbers...so above return i need to be:

```
data.genre = [ '2', '3' ];
```

I try with this:

```
alert(data.genre.map(function(x){ return x.replace(/^\d+\.\s*/,"") }));
```

But nothing is changed...so i need to make whole array remove strings and leave only numbers...this i need to get id with this numbers in my mysql left join genre on id.

Comment: You should be using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) not `map.`

Comment: So `data` should be an object not array?

Comment: Can this be used as regex or somthing familiar? that removes string

Comment: Do you want to keep `"1.2"`?

Comment: Above answer is correct..simple and easy..thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could filter with a regular expression which test for digits only.

```js
var data = {};
data.genre = [ 'AAAA', '2', 'CCCc', '3', 'dDdDD' ];

data.genre = data.genre.filter(function (a) {
    return /^\d+$/.test(a);
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: the former version was better, why did you make it more complex ?

Comment: Instead of that insanity, why not `.filter(//.test, /^\d+$/)`?

Comment: ok, you get the old version back.

Comment: @torazaburo no the present edit is better. At least consider the OP, he should be able to know how the code works

Comment: @torazaburo now I wish I could undo my upvote on your comment. That's a comment, not a regular expression, and `RegExp.prototype.test` is better anyway because it does not create an unused variable.

Comment: @torazaburo, that ivokes others who do not like to misuse thisArg.

Comment: @torazaburo actually `//.test` makes a comment.

Comment: You're right, although it worked when typed directly into the console. So make it `/./` like you did.

Comment: @torazaburo you should write your own answer if you prefer it that way.

Comment: Well, this whole answer is flawed anyway, since it won't handle `"1.2"`, or `"2e0"`, which we might assume the OP wants to keep.

Comment: There's no indication of that. Since it wasn't specified, this is a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: Wouldn't `!/\D/.test(a)` be cleaner?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var data = {};
data.genre = [ 'AAAA', '2', 'CCCc', '3', 'dDdDD', '', ' ' ];

data.genre = data.genre.filter(function (str) {
  return str.trim() && !isNaN(str);
});

console.log(data.genre);
```

This method uses the global function [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to determine if the string can be coerced to a numerical value. If not, `isNaN()` returns `true` so we must negate `!` that, in order to filter numeric strings. In addition, it preflights this check with [`String#trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim), and empty strings evaluated as a Boolean are falsy, so strings with whitespace only *shall not pass*.

Another comment, make sure that you declare `data` as an object `{}` instead of an array `[]` if you're going to assign it arbitrary properties. Arrays are used for storing ordered data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for this.
Array.filter takes in a callback function which should return true or false and will composite a new array based on the true/false outputs.